# How to sample in Tensorflow by custom probability distribution?

Tags: tensorflow, sampling, probability-distribution

I have a vector e.g., `V = [10, 30, 20, 50]` of N elements and a probability vector `P = [.2, .3, .1, .4]`. In tensorflow, how can I randomly sample K elements from  V that obey the given probability distribution P? I want the sampling to be done with replacement.

Comment: Check if following help: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical

Answer (score 3):

[`tf.nn.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler) does more or less what you want. The trouble is, it can only take int32 arguments as the unigrams parameter (probability distribution) because it was designed for high-number multiclass processing, such as language processing. You can multiply the numbers in the probability distribution to get to an integer, but only to a limit of accuracy.

Put the desired number of samples in `num_samples` and the probability weights into `unigrams` (has to be int32.) The parameter `true_classes` has to be filled with the same number of elements as `num_true`, but otherwise irrelevant, because you will get the indices back (and then use those to pull the sample.) `unique` can be changed to True as desired.

This is tested code for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.Session()

V = tf.constant( np.array( [[ 10, 30, 20, 50 ]]), dtype=tf.int64)

sampled_ids, true_expected_count, sampled_expected_count = tf.nn.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler(
   true_classes = V,
   num_true = 4,
   num_sampled = 50,
   unique = False,
   range_max = 4,
   unigrams = [ 20, 30, 10, 40 ] # this is P, times 100
)
sample = tf.gather( V[ 0 ], sampled_ids )
x = sess.run( sample )
print( x )
```

Output:

> [50 20 10 30 30 30 10 30 20 50 50 50 10 50 10 30 50 50 30 30 50 10 20 30
>    50 50 50 50 30 50 50 30 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 10 50 30 50 10 50 50 10 30
>    50 50]

If you really want to use float32 probability values, then you have to create the sampler from several parts (no one operation exists for this), like this (tested code):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.Session()

k = 50 # number of samples you want
V = tf.constant( [ 10, 30, 20, 50 ], dtype = tf.float32 ) # values
P = tf.constant( [ 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4 ], dtype = tf.float32 ) # prob dist

cum_dist = tf.cumsum( P ) # create cumulative probability distribution

# get random values between 0 and the max of cum_dist
# we'll determine where it is in the cumulative distribution
rand_unif = tf.random_uniform( shape=( k, ), minval = 0.0, maxval = tf.reduce_max( cum_dist ), dtype = tf.float32 )

# create boolean to signal where the random number is greater than the cum_dist
# take advantage of broadcasting to create Cartesian product
greater = tf.expand_dims( rand_unif, axis = -1 ) > tf.expand_dims( cum_dist, axis = 0 )

# we get the indices by counting how many are greater in any given row
idxs = tf.reduce_sum( tf.cast( greater, dtype = tf.int64 ), 1 )

# then just gather the sample from V by the indices
sample = tf.gather( V, idxs )

# run, output
print( sess.run( sample ) )
```

Output:

> [20. 10. 50. 50. 20. 30. 10. 20. 30. 50. 20. 50. 30. 50. 30. 50. 50. 50.
>    50. 50. 50. 30. 20. 20. 20. 10. 50. 30. 30. 10. 50. 50. 50. 20. 30. 50.
>    30. 10. 50. 20. 30. 50. 30. 10. 10. 50. 50. 20. 50. 30.]

Comment: Actually, my input numbers and the probability are both in float. The probability values can be really small.

Comment: Added float32 version to answer

Answer (score 2):

`tf.distributions.Categorical()` might be the way to do it in a one liner. According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Categorical) page, given a probability distribution `P` defined over `N` values, `tf.distributions.Categorical()` can generate integers `0, 1, ..., N-1` with probabilities `P[0], P[1], ..., P[N-1]`. The generated integers can be interpreted as indices for the vector `V`. Following code snippet illustrates this:

```
# Probability distribution
P = [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4]

# Vector of values
V = [10, 30, 20, 50]

# Define categorical distribution
dist = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=P)

# Generate a sample from categorical distribution - this serves as an index
index = dist.sample().eval()

# Fetch the value at V[index] as the sample
sample = V[index]
```

All of this can be done in a one liner:

```
sample = V[tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=P).sample().eval()]
```

If want to generate `K` samples from this distribution, wrap the above one liner in a list comprehension:

```
samples = [ V[tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=P).sample().eval()] for i in range(K) ]
```

Output of above code for K = 30:

> [50, 10, 30, 50, 30, 20, 50, 30, 50, 50, 30, 50, 30, 50, 20, 10, 50, 20, 30, 30, 50, 50, 50, 30, 20, 50, 30, 30, 50, 50]

There might be better ways than using list comprehension though.